# Port 81 and 82 doesnt work (Microsoft Azure Ubuntu 18.04 VM)

Tags: azure, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to set up two NGINX servers on my azure virtual machine. It worked fine when I curled it from the vm. When I ran curl localhost:81 on the vm, it returned the page content. But when I went to my actual computer and ran curl azurevmspublicip:81 it refused to connect. Is there something else Im missing? Do I need to set up additional rules in Microsoft Azure? Do I need to configure something in azure?

Comment: Welcome! This should be posted to the unix stack exchange, or superuser, not here (it's not programming-related). I suspect you'll need to provide a bit more detail when you post there though.

Comment: I saw other people post questions about azure hosting though @DavidMakogon

Comment: I can't speak for others, but... this is a general computing question. If you had some software running in a vm or other Azure service, and your queston was related to the app you wrote, and had something programming-related, then this is absolutely the place.

Comment: Ok                            ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵